# Using Font Awesome library in a Shopify store

Tags: font-face, shopify, font-awesome

I'm trying to use Font Awesome:

http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/

I've used these font icons on several Rails projects with no problem but for some reason when I try to use them in a Shopify store they don't get rendered.

I'm using another @font-face with no difficulties but for some reason this @font-face is not rendering.

In assets/ I have:

```
fontawesome-webfont.eot
fontawesome-webfont.svg
fontawesome-webfont.ttf
fontawesome-webfont.woff
```

And I load them with @font-face just like I do with another font-face that works fine.
in my stylesheet.css which lives in assets/

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  src: url('fontawesome-webfont.eot');
  src: url('fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('eot'), 
    url('fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
    url('fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), 
    url('fontawesome-webfont.svg#FontAwesome') format('svg');
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal;
  }
```

But when I try to use the icons they can't seem to load.  Any idea why this isn't working on Shopify?  I feel like I'm missing something small but I can't figure it out.

Comment: You'll have to use liquid's asset_url in the CSS; if that doesn't work for you here are the files all 'Shopified': https://github.com/nairdairda/Shopify-Font-Awesome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to use the liquid asset URL helper in your CSS. More docs on the asset URL helper can be found here https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/filters/url-filters#asset_url

Comment: I'm currently using a @font-face that is working without the liquid asset url.  My .css file is in the assets directory and my .eot, .svg, .ttf, .woff fonts live in assets also.

If I use the asset URL helper then make my .css file into a .css.liquid file ?

Comment: Yes, rename your .css to .css.liquid, and use the asset URL helper as John mentioned.

Answer (score 28):

The simplest solution is to attach this to header of theme.liquid

```
<!-- Font-Awesome ================================================== -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

No extra uploading. No installation. No hassle. Done.

Thank you MaxCDN :)

Comment: Easiest for me! Thanks buddy,

Comment: This is going to increase shopify site load time by a few seconds or milliseconds as it is external CDN

Answer (score 1):

The posts here are a bit out-dated. I had to do a bit of troubleshooting still.

I went with the CDN approach and included a `<link />` tag in my `/layout/theme.liquid` head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha256-h20CPZ0QyXlBuAw7A+KluUYx/3pK+c7lYEpqLTlxjYQ=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

I got the CDN link from this website: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/font-awesome

Comment: Yes, the accepted answer is outdated. I used this answer on 10/2020 and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You must remove `#iefix` and `#FontAwesome` in the `@font-face` code. Here's the correct code:

```
@font-face {
font-family: "FontAwesome";
src: url('fontawesome-webfont.eot');
src: url('fontawesome-webfont.eot?') format('eot'), url('fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fontawesome-webfont.svg') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
theme.liquid

  Before the head tag </head>
```

```css
    
    font-awesome.css
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'FontAwesome';
      src: url('fontawesome-webfont.eot');
      /* src: url('/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.7.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0') format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.7.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
      */ font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal;
```

```html
    
 
    
        {{ 'font-awesome'| stylesheet_tag }} 
        <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/46b6d6c6a9.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ 'fontawesome.min.js' | asset_url }}"></script>
     
        </head>
    
    
     any where into body section  use the font icon 
    
    <div class="mb-2 col-2"> <span class="fa fa-reddit social"></span> </div>
                            <div class="mb-2 col-2"> <span class="fa fa-facebook social"></span> </div>
```