# Why am I still seeing 404 errors for font files that I have removed in my shopify project?

Tags: shopify

I tried loading font awesome font files:

```
FontAwesome.otf
fontawesome-webfont.svg
fontawesome-webfont.woff
fontawesome-webfont.eot 
fontawesome-webfont.ttf
fontawesome-webfont.woff2
```

However I was getting a bunch of `404` errors when I tried to load these files with shopify's `asset_url`. These are the `404` requests:

```
https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0055/8845/1441/t/4/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0
https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0055/8845/1441/t/4/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0
https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0055/8845/1441/t/4/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0
```

I saw this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28558422/2524631), and decided to surrender to simplicity and just linked the font-awesome assets in my head with:

```
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

The `link` that contains the font-awesome url in the head is working, and I am seeing font awesome icons on my page. Moreover, I have also removed the font files above from the `/assets` directory seeing as that I was getting a bunch of `404` errors. However, I am still seeing the errors despite removing the font files from `/assets`.

Despite having removed the font files from `/assets` why am I still seeing these `404` errors? Does Shopify cache assets for a period of time even if you have removed them from the project?

Answer (score 0):

Do you still have the have the files linked in your code? If you have files linked in your code and they are not there it will be the same as if you gave the wrong pathway to the files originally.

A 404 error is thrown when a client tries to access a resource on the server that is not present (i.e. not found). Check your code for where you originally linked the fontawesome files and remove those. The client will no longer request the resources and the 404 error will go away.